# about register_shutdown_function and destruct function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have 2 question about wordpress (`wp-includes/wp-db.php`) code:

1. why destruct function return true? what this mean?!

   > ```
   > function __construct( $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost ) {
   >     register_shutdown_function( array( &$this, '__destruct' ) );
   >     ....
   > }
   > function __destruct() {
   >     return true;
   > }
   > ```
2. also why [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) input parameter is array? can `register_shutdown_function` accept array as input?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the code posted `__destruct()` doesn't do anything. It just returns.
2. `array( $this, 'method-name' )` is how you pass a callback function if that callback is a class method and you are in object context when you pass the callback.

For example:

```
class DummyObject() {
  class __construct() {
    function_that_takes_callback( array($this,'callback_function') );
  }

  function callback_function() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Outside of a class that would like:

```
function_that_takes_callback( 'callback_function');
function callback_function() {
  // do stuff
}
```